InviteReferrals - authentication success but conversion failed
I have been working on a PHP referral program, and my conversions have been failing for the past two days. I haven't encountered this problem before.
<html>

<head>

    <title>PHP</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script>
        if (top != self) {
            top.location.replace(document.location);
            alert("[PHP]For Security Reasons, Framing is Not Allowed, Click OK to Remove The Frames")
        }

        function copyToClipboard() {
            var copyText = document.getElementById("copyText");


            copyText.select(); // select the text field
            document.execCommand("copy"); // copy the selected text to the clipboard
            alert("Copied to clipboard: " + copyText.value);
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2><u>Verify</u></h2>

    <?php

    include 'function.php';

    function CURL($url, $data, $headers, $method, $header_send)
    {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header_send);
        $output = curl_exec($curl);
        return $output;
    }

    if (isset($_GET['submit1'])) {

        $ipaddress = file_get_contents("https://pro.ip-api.com/json/?key=LWKtz4EzQwMJRyQ");
        // echo $ipaddress;

        $data89 = json_decode($ipaddress, true);

        // Check if decoding was successful and "query" field exists
        if ($data89 && isset($data89['query'])) {
            // Access the "query" field
            $query = $data89['query'];
            echo "IP ADDRESS : $query";
            echo "<br><br>";
        }

        $otp = $_GET['otp'];
        $sr = $_GET['sr'];
        $bd = $_GET['bd'];
        $bddd = $_GET['bddd'];
        $avn = $_GET['avn'];
        $dd = $_GET['dd'];
        $ir = $_GET['ir'];
        $ir_code = $_GET['ircode'];
        $now = time();

        $url2 = "https://hittv.in/api/verify-otp";
        $headers2 = array(
            "Host: hittv.in",
            "accept: application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "user-agent: okhttp/4.9.2",
        );

        $data2 = "phoneNumber=$sr&otp=$otp";
        $resp2 = CURL($url2, $data2, $headers2, 'POST', '0');
        $obj = json_decode($resp2, true);
        $status = $obj['status'];
        $token = $obj['token'];
        $user_id = $obj['user_id'];

        if ($status == "success") {
            $url3 = "https://www.ref-r.com/campaign/mobile_app/tracking";
            $headers3 = array(
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android $avn; $bddd Build/MRA58K)",
                "Connection: Keep-Alive",
                "Host: www.ref-r.com",
            );
            $data3 = "bid=XXXXX&bid_e=9E07DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&event=register&android_id=$dd&mobile=$num&fname=$uname&referCode=$ir_code&referrer=$ir&referrerSource=finger-print&orderID=$user_id&networkSSID=$brand";

            $resp3 = CURL($url3, $data3, $headers3, 'POST', '0');
            $obj4 = json_decode($resp3, 1);

            echo "<div class='ver'><pre>";
            echo preg_replace('/^\s+/m', '', print_r($obj4, true));
            echo "</pre></div>";

            echo '<div class="success"><b> ' . $sr . '<form>
                <input type="text" id="copyText" value="' . $token . '">
                <button type="button" onclick="copyToClipboard()">COPY</button>
                </form></b></div><br>';


            $data_file = "details_new.json";
            $message = '';
            $dt = date("d-m-y h:i:s A");
            if (!file_exists($data_file)) {
                $fh = fopen($data_file, 'w+');
                fwrite($fh, $message);
            }
            $array_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($data_file), 1);
            $printdata = array("Userid" => "$user_id", "SR" => "$sr", "Number" => "$num", "DeviceId" => "$dd", "Token" => "$token");
            $array_data[] = $printdata;
            $final_data = json_encode($array_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            if (file_put_contents($data_file, $final_data));
        }
    }

    ?>

</body>

</html>


OUTPUT
Array
(
[bid] => XXXXX
[bid_e] => 9E07DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[Authentication] => success
[conversion_details] => Array
(
[conversion] => fail
)
)

I've read the InviteReferrals API documentation, but it didn't help. There might be an issue with missing parameters, but I can't identify which ones are missing.

I can not follow your problem description. What do you want to do? What is the error message? Reduce the code to a only minimal reproducible example.

When sending API requests, my conversions usually succeed, but for the past two days, they have been failing, even though the API is still working. I want to understand why the conversions are failing so I can fix the error.

Did you change any code? Maybe it is on the other side.

No, I didn't. I think the API is requesting some more parameters which I am not sending.
Is there any way to find what is requested by the API?
$data3 = "bid=67335&bid_e=9E07D3BA06DBDB90B475406FA37A0D01&event=register&android_id=$dd&mobile=$num&fname=$uname&referCode=$ir_code&referrer=$ir&referrerSource=finger-print&orderID=$user_id&networkSSID=$brand";

Is there any way to find what is requested by the API? - hm, what about documentation?
